# Stuck at laravel query with AND and Where

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need your help. I try to do this query:

```
     public function future_trips($cat_id, $city_id)
        {
            $trips=Events::where('start_date','>',Carbon::now()->subDay(5))
                ->where(function ($q)
                {
                    $q->where('category_id',$cat_id)->orWhere('city', $city_id);
                })
                ->get();
}
```

> ErrorException: Undefined variable: cat_id  in file C:\x......
>
> Undefined variable $cat_id less... (Ctrl+F1)  The inspection can
>   produce two types of warnings: The definition of the variable can not
>   be found anywhere. ("Undefined variable") There are one or more paths
>   to reach the line with the variable usage without defining it.
>   ("Variable might have not been defined")

Can somebody explain me why ?

Comment: How is it called? What is passed as arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add these variables to the function closure with `use`. Php does not automatically include variables outside the closure.

```
public function future_trips($cat_id, $city_id)
{
    $trips = Events::where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDay(5))
        ->where(function ($q) use ($cat_id, $city_id)
        {
            $q->where('category_id',$cat_id)->orWhere('city', $city_id);
        })
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: @Alphal1111 if this answer solves your problem then you should mark it as the accepted answer